# Регулярные выражения, вырезать адрес

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть определенного рода проблемы с многоэтажными регулярками. Подскажите как оформить.

**Ввод:** тысяча коротких текстов, в некоторых из которых есть адреса.

**Примеры ввода:**

- ...адрес: Россия Самарская область, г.Самара, ул.Ленина, 1...
- ...местоположение г.Оренбург, Ленина, д.1...
- ...адрес город Москва, Ленина, 1, кв.1...
- ...располагается по адресу: Ленинградская область, село Ленина, д.1...
- ...местонахождение: курганская Область...

**Задача:** выловить большинство адресов и не захватить лишнего после них.

**Мои мысли по алгоритму:** как видно из примеров - адреса не унифицированы и сложно зацепиться за что-то, чтобы гарантированно выдернуть полный адрес, поэтому нас устроит адрес максимальной длины, лишь бы без лишней случайно захваченной информации.
Поэтому в начале строки цепляемся за слово `адрес` или `местоположение`. И начинаем углубляться: следующая проверка должна быть на `(область|край|регион)`, далее `(г\.|город|село|поселок)`, далее `(ул\.|улица)`.

Моя проблема в том, что регулярки мне дались только на базовом уровне и задачу не могу победить вторые сутки.

На данном этапе имею регулярку `'/адрес[у: ]{1,3}?.*г\.[ ]?[а-яА-Я]*/ui'` и много вопросов.

1) Регулярка не учитывает начало в виде слова `местоположение`, я пробую добавить его таким образом `'/(адрес[у: ]{1,3}?|местоположение).*г\.[ ]?[а-яА-Я]*/ui'`. В ответ регулярка начинает слать бред. Как правильно оформить `ИЛИ` в данном случае?

2) Похожая проблема получается тогда, когда я пытаются подставить разные формы населенного пункта `'/адрес[у: ]{1,3}?.*(г\.|город|село|поселок)[ ]?[а-яА-Я]*/ui'`

3) По итогу мне надо сохранять адрес максимально успешной длины. Но если я ставлю проверку на `область` перед городом, то само собой не получу в результатах адреса без области.

В целом пункт 3 планирую решить через PHP по следующему алгоритму:

1. если успешна регулярка выборки улицы, то берем резутат, иначе
2. если успешна регулярка выборки города, то берем результат, иначе
3. если успешна регулярка выборки области, то берем результат, иначе
4. адреса нет

Но для этого мне надо решить вопросы 1 и 2.

Спасибо коллеги!

Comment: [`~(?:адресу?|место(?:положение|нахождение)):?[^\n]+~`](https://regex101.com/r/Ya02L5/1) ?

Comment: Спасибо Эдуард. Вынесите в ответы, отмечу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Нас устроит адрес максимальной длины*

Нужно реализовать привязку к словам: `местоположение`, `адрес`, `адресу` и `местонахождение`, после которых будет необязательный символ двоеточия `:`, после чего захватить оставшуюся часть подстроки до символа перевода каретки на новую строку `\n`:

[`~(?:адресу?|место(?:положение|нахождение)):?[^\n]+~`](https://regex101.com/r/Ya02L5/1)

---

> *P.S.: Вариант не идеальный, т.к. вероятно придётся удалять лишние символы из полученного результата.*